# Populate SWF with SQL data

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I designed a Flash application that takes data from an XML file and populates a datagrid and textFields.

I need to access a SQL database instead of XML.

Can you lead me in the right direction? I have seen Flash Builder access SQL, but I am not sure how to populate the datagrid in the SWF. The SWF contains a map and other graphic elements and animation.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your server side? Do you need to access MySQL database directly? Can you use PHP or .NET or other data access layer?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that you create a PHP file that accesses the database and prints/echoes the MYSQL data as your XML. Using the URLLoader class you can load this php file and have the xml as the loaded data. The rest should then be the same as your existing app.

You can add get variables to the url string used in the URLLoader or you can use URLVariables to use post variables to pass values if necessary to your php script.